# Refreshing a PHP request automatically without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, refresh

As of right now, I have a PHP page that automatically refreshes every 8 seconds. When it refreshes, it updates information on the page that it gets from an API. How do I refresh the PHP script [clear the current data/html text, echo the new data] without refreshing the page? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use ajax.. you cannot do it with just hp, you need client side javascript language. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I'm not sure how... Can you give me a quick example as to how this would be done?

Comment: You need to learn to use AJAX with javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a page that contains ajax code, (javascript or jquery). Here its jquery ajax(its simple)
create another php page and put all required php code there. 
So we have page 1 with ajax and page 2 with php code

in page 1

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "yourphppage.php",  //php page link here
  data: { name: "John"}  // send any data to php page if needed
})
  .done(function( msg ) {   //msg contains the response from php page...
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );   //use msg to update the page without refresh
  });
```

now in page 2 add the php code you have... this page 2 will return response to page 1. This is how ajax works and the result is a page that updates without full refresh

Comment: I see. Where would I put the code to run this script every 8 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with PHP, you need to make an ajax request by javascript.

An example of how to do it:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/